# What is the difference between ls -la and ls -l in Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

`ls -la` and `ls -l` both provide more information than the `ls` command. However, 
as their outputs are very similar, 
I'm not clear what the difference between the two commands is.

What is the difference between `ls -la` and `ls -l` in git bash?

Comment: The best reference for this kind of questions is the manual of the command, which you can look at with `man ls` (or `info ls`).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the meaning of the flags below.  Both are not the same.  In the first case (`ls -l`) hidden files/folders *will not* be listed while in the second case (`ls -la`) hidden files/folders *will* be shown.

```
-l

-l                         use a long listing format


-a

-a, --all                  do not ignore entries starting with .
```

which means show hidden files/directories as well.

Comment: One may add, that hidden files on windows work different than on *nix systems, hence on windows output may look the same.